# Check if user is online for a chat app made using Firebase

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, codeigniter-3

Using Real Time Database of Firebase to create a Chat App.

The users class looks like this (default is JSON in Firebase)

```
"users" : {
     "-K2ib62mjHh34CAUfig" : {
      "lastvisibleat" : "2016-09-30 07:10:40",
      "name" : "Peter Parker",
      "online" : "1"
    },
    "--K2ib62mjHh34CAUh18" : {
      "lastvisibleat" : "2016-09-30 07:26:17",
      "name" : "Riddhi Dixit",
      "online" : "1"
    }
}
```

I want to change the status from `online: "1"` to `online : "0"` when the user's internet suddenly gets unavailable or browser crashes of its own or something as such that cannot be handled with `sess_destroy()` method of CodeIgniter.

Server is build in PHP using CodeIgniter.

Comment: I am going to implement the online-offline feature for the user, I have not stored the information of  the user in firebase real-time database instead of it I am using the authorization (registering the user with email and password on firebase) ; so is it necessary to store the users information in database tree too to implement this feature??

Comment: @SaimAbdullah Yes you will have to and use a cron to ping the user to check its status

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using Firebase's built-in `onDisconnect()` hook. It enables you to predefine an operation that will happen as soon as the client becomes disconnected.

See Firebase documentation:
[Managing presence for Web clients](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-presence).

The linked document targets web clients, but equivalent functionality is available for [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence) and [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-presence) clients too.